Not able to publish MS Teams bot to App Store
I'm developing a MS Teams bot. It's nearly done and tested using side loading option and uploading to Org's catalogue as well.
The issue is when I tried publishing it Teams Store via Developer Portal, I'm getting no feedback whatsoever. It simply closes. Please find the ScreenShot attached. Note: I have cut does some part of the screen to hide sensitive information.
Also, only this option causes this other options to upload in catalog and downloading works fine. I'm not able to figure out the issue and it's not showing any kind of error or feedback either.
I was expecting the app to get published to app store once following through these steps but struggling with it.

Could you please share the screenshot?
